# Sudden drop in drive performance across all drives

Tags: hard-drive

I have a NAS server running Ubuntu Server on a VM under windows and recently I had all the drives that are part of the VM drop in sequential read/write performance from 95 to 125MB/s reads and writes on each drive to ~30MB/s reads and writes.

The server has access to 6 physical drives: 5 in an external USB enclosure (2 in raid 0) and 1 more in the computer chassis. 4 of the drives and 4tb Seagate Barracuda Drives and two are generic HGST 6tb enterprise drives. All are formatted with NTFS since I occasionally need to directly connect to windows with them.
the server is running both samba and minidlna servers

troubleshooting steps that I've done so far.

-test drive performance directly under ubuntu using the dd command. all drives ~30MB/s with the exception of the raid drive which is ~20MB/s.

-disconnect drives and test directly in windows using CrystalDiskMark. same result for speed, .

-run chkdsk /f on all drives. no issues

-run defrag /a on all drives. <1% fragmentation

-check S.M.A.R.T data on drives, no issues.

any further troubleshooting steps that I can try would be very welcome. I'd like to be able to get the drive performance back up to the level where I can saturate the gigabit network connection like it was able to before.

Comment: Do you have by chance a sandy bridge CPU? First revision of P67 chipsets had problems with SATA2 ports performance degrading over time. In any case information about your hardware can be relevant.

Comment: running an i7-6950x, x99 chipset, 128gb ram. the external usb drive enclosure is a teramaster d5-300C for 5 drives and the last drive is wired directly to the motherboard on one of the chipset sata3 ports. there were no hardware changes that corresponded with the performance drop.